# Magento 2 timing of transactional emails sent

Tags: magento2, cron, email-scheduler

By default it takes around 10-15 minutes from what I can tell to receive a transactional email.  The email cron on the server is set to every minute.

How / Where in Magento 2 (2.0.7) can I shorten the time it takes to send a transactional email?  Thoughts?

[image: Cron settings in admin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out cron setting from here

> Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Advanced >> System >> Cron
>   (Sheduled Tasks)

Change your value in : **Cron configuration options for group: default**

You can change cron setting by this configuration sections.

Comment: I added a picture of my settings.  Which group does the transactional email belong to? index or default?  default right?

Comment: group : default.

Comment: Okey I am updating my answer.